# Align two vector with common elements

Tags: r, join

I have two vectors where some elements are common:

```
v1= c('a', 'b', 'c')
v2 = c('b', 'c', 'd')
```

I want to combine the vectors into two `data.frame`s. In the first I want all elements from both vectors, and non-matching positions in either vector should be replaced by `NA`:

```
v1   v2
a    NA
b    b
c    c
NA   d
```

In the second data frame, I want the elements from from the first vector and the corresponding matches in the second:

```
v1   v2
a    NA
b    b
c    c
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Get the first one

```
mergedf=merge(data.frame('key'=v1,v1),data.frame('key'=v2,v2),by='key',all=T)
mergedf
  key   v1   v2
1   a    a <NA>
2   b    b    b
3   c    c    c
4   d <NA>    d
```

Get the 2nd df

```
mergedf[!is.na(mergedf$v1),]
  key   v1   v2
1   a    a <NA>
2   b    b    b
3   c    c    c
4   d <NA>    d
```

Comment: You're missing a comma, `mergedf[!is.na(mergedf$v1), ]`.

Comment: Is there any better way to do that? I feel like that but do not know how...

Answer (score 1):

An option can be to go for `dplyr` based solution. You can use `full_join` and `left_join` as:

```
library(dplyr)

v1= c('a', 'b', 'c')
v2 = c('b', 'c', 'd')

full_join(data.frame(key=v1, v1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
          data.frame(key=v2, v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), by="key") %>%
  select(-key)

#     v1   v2
# 1    a <NA>
# 2    b    b
# 3    c    c
# 4 <NA>    d


left_join(data.frame(key=v1, v1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
          data.frame(key=v2, v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), by="key") %>%
  select(-key)

#   v1   v2
# 1  a <NA>
# 2  b    b
# 3  c    c
```